# Avoid xml escaping of angle brackets, when passing xml string to System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I'm getting a string from `string GetXmlString()`; this I cant change.

I have to append this to an xml within a `new XElement ("parent" , ... );` , to the `...` area.

This string I'm getting is of the following format.

```
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
...
```

The final result I want is this to be like

```
<parent>
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
<tag name="" value =""></tag>
...
</parent>
```

when I just pass the string as `XElement("root", GetXmlString())` 
**<** and **>** are encoded to `&lt;` and `&gt`

When I try `XElement.Parse(GetXmlString())` or `XDocument.Parse(GetXmlString())` I get the **There are multiple root elements** exception.

How do I get the required output without escaping the brackets? What am I missing?

Comment: That's not "ASCII encoding" - it's XML escaping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to *give* it a root element, then parse it as XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<parent>" + text + "</parent>");
```

If you need to append to an existing element, you can use:

```
var elements = XElement.Parse("<parent>" + text + "</parent>").Elements();
existingElement.Add(elements);
```

Comment: My question was a bit misleading. I have done a little edit.
I have to stick to the final result format given. also there are multipe `parent` elements too. Your solution adds another `root` element within the `parent ` element right?

Comment: @DanDole: No, it doesn't - it didn't have the `parent` element at all. All you had to do was change `root` to `parent`, and you have the complete results. No need for `new XElement("parent", ...)` at all, unless you need to add it to an *existing* element - which is still easy, but it's not clear from your question what you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Jon's suggestion would be to create an `XmlReader` for your fragment and parse from that:

```
var element = new XElement("parent");

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};

var text = GetXmlString();

using (var sr = new StringReader(text))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
{
    xr.MoveToContent();

    while (!xr.EOF)
    {
        var node = XNode.ReadFrom(xr);   
        element.Add(node);
    }
}
```

This would be useful if the 'parent' element already exists, else simple concatenation of the XML nodes at each end and parsing would be simpler.